# Can one convert output from the Cloud to Latex?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

I have the following command in Mathematica Developer Cloud:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];

{Z, Y} = 
  AsymptoticDSolveValue[
    {y'''[t] == (c1 - t^2)*z[t], 
     z'''[t] == (-c2 - t^2)*y[t], 
     y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1, y''[0] == 1, 
     z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 1, z''[0] == 1}, 
    {z, y}, {t, 0, 10}]

WorkingPrecision -> 30

Plot[Evaluate[{Z, Y} /. c1 -> 1 /. c2 -> 1], {t, -7, 7}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]"}]

TexForm[output]
```

This outputs a plot and the series functions. How can I generate the series functions in Tex format also? I tried TexForm, but I am not sure it helped.

Comment: The output is not only a plot, but also series functions. It is those that are needed in Tex form. Thanks for pointing this out. I will clarify that in the OP.

Comment: `TeXForm` works fine for me. If it doesn't work for you, please show a complete example.

Comment: ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];(* Clear and Remove all variables *)

{Z, Y} = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{
y'''[t] == (c1 - t^2)*z[t], 
z'''[t] == (-c2 - t^2)*y[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1, y''[0] == 1, 
z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 1, z''[0] == 1}, 
{z, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
WorkingPrecision -> 30
Plot[Evaluate[{Z, Y} /. c1 -> 1 /. c2 -> 1], {t, -7, 7}, 
PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]"}]
TexForm

Comment: I can't read your code because it is not formatted correctly. It should be included in the main post (not a comment) and placed in a code block. However, I *can* see that you misspelt `TeXForm` (capital X) and that you did not actually apply it at all (it's a function).

Comment: I am not sure here, because the output does not have a name. I made the suggested change in the OP.

Comment: Your OP still has `Texform` instead of `TeXForm`. You also don't include the definition of `output`.

Comment: I am really not sure how to define the output by some name, it is without name in the output from the command. Once I changed it to TexForm it still gives no answer. How do I define that name ?

Comment: If you can't show us what the problem is, we can't help. You must find a way to explain the problem.  Also, after at least three tries, you are still misspelling `TeXForm`.  Capitalization matters.

Comment: Use `TeXForm[Z]` and `TeXForm[Y]` (with capital X!). And for the plot, you can try `plot = Plot[Evaluate[{Z, Y} /. c1 -> 1 /. c2 -> 1], {t, -7, 7}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]"}]; Export["<<filename of yourchoice>>.pdf",plot]` and use `\includegraphics` within $\LaTeX$/

Comment: Thanks  @HenrikSchumacher! It works now! All the best

Comment: You're welcome.